# Flutter MySql Data Not Showing First Time

Tags: mysql, flutter

I have MySQL database connection. I can fetch data and I can print the data I received on the console, but I cannot see it on the screen only first time.

DB method :

```sql
Mysql db = Mysql();
      db.getConnection().then((conn) {
      String sql = 'select correctCount from users where uid = "$uid"';
      conn.query(sql).then((results) async {
       for (var row in results) {
         correctCountStats = row[0];
         debugPrint(correctCountStats.toString());
       }
     });
   });
```

My UI :

```
Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: primaryColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
           width: context.dynamicWidth(6),
           height: context.dynamicHeight(30),
           child: Center(
           child: Text(
           correctCountStats,
             style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline6
                    ?.copyWith(color: whiteColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              )
           ),
         )
```

As I said I can see the correctCountStats in the console but not the first time on the screen. I need to change page and come back with Bottom Navigation bar.

I was try future builder, and set state but everything is same.

Answer (score 0):

To view data you have to change the state of your screen. You can do so by using setState.

```
Mysql db = Mysql();
  db.getConnection().then((conn) {
  String sql = 'select correctCount from users where uid = "$uid"';
  conn.query(sql).then((results) async {
   for (var row in results) {
   //This will display data on your screen
   setState(() {
        correctCountStats = row[0];
    });
   
     debugPrint(correctCountStats.toString());
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: You should be using `FutureBuilder` to build your UI if you are fetching data from a database or an API.